# How can I read only one character and ignore the others if the users types more?

Tags: c, input, character

I have a project that must be made only in C (I'm not allowed to use C++).
Right now I'm working on the UI (a little menu showed in the console, each option has a number from 0 to 6 assigned to it, the user typed the number, hits enter and so on).

I'm having a problem with the reading option function.

At first I tried

```
int option;
scanf("%d", &option);
```

but this caused problems when I typed in characters.

I tried reading a char:

```
char option;
scanf("%s", &option);
option -= '0';
```

This allowed me to treat it like a number and worked nice for the first tests, allowing me to verify if the option is valid (it's not a letter, it's a number between 0 and 6).

The problem is that I can type more than one character and all of them will be stored somewhere in memory. And that's obviously bad.

I tried reading with `"%c"`, but that will display the error message for every character in the string I entered.

To make it a bit more clear, this is the function

```
int readOption(int maxOp)
{
    char option = -1;
    while(option < 0 || option > maxOp)
    {
        scanf("%c", &option);
        option -= '0';
        if(option < 0 || option > maxOp)
            printf("Invalid option!\nTry again: \n");
    }
    return option;
}
```

If I type "`abc`", the error message will be printed 3 times.

So how can I make sure that any extra characters entered are ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
int ch;
scanf(" %c", &option);
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n');
```

Comment: This solved almost all the problems. It has a little disadvantage: If i type "1a" it will count as option 1, but I think that's what I get if I ignore extra characters. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, buy you may try something like this:

```
scanf(" %[0-6]1d*[^\n]", &option);
```

The call to `scanf` will only be valid if the input is a single number between 0 and 6, ignoring leading spaces. `*` suppresses any character after that isn't in this range and that is not a newline.

Comment: I never knew that scanf works with regular expressions. This didn't work (oddly enough it caused and infinite loop of "Invalid option!"), but this will help me in other areas :) And I'm going to try to explore this a little more, maybe it will work.

Comment: @user3002428 Actually, `scanf` doesn't work with "standard" regular expression, it has its own syntax; I am sure the solution should be close to what I proposed (I'm going to try and actually test it), though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getc()` to do the job like this:

```
int main(){
    char choice = getc(stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
}
```

Now `choice` is the first entered character, everything entered after the first character is deleted so it won't interrupt any other user inputs.

In general, when the user enters input it's stored in a special buffer called `stdin`, if you don't delete that buffer after reading the first character using `fflush(stdin)` it will interrupt any future user inputs.